# Multiple definition in gthr-default.h

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

So I am doing this in a header file gui_base.hpp
"gui_flags" is simply a definition of bitflags,
nsp_input is needed to access a variable in "handle mouse"
and in gui_text.hpp i declare the textblock class.
Every "gui_" file is in the GUI:: namespace.

```
#ifndef _GUI_BASE_HPP_
#define _GUI_BASE_HPP_

#include "gui_flags.hpp"
#include "nsp_input.hpp"
#include "gui_text.hpp"


class GUI::base
{
protected:
  struct s_lastclick
  {
    float ltime,rtime;
    glm::vec2 pos;
    bool rc, lc, first;
  };

  std::string m_name;

  float m_width;
  float m_height;

  glm::vec2 m_center;
  glm::mat2x2 m_tlbr;

  GUI_FLAGS m_flags;

  s_lastclick m_lastclick;
  textblock m_textblock;



  std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<base>> m_slaves;

  glm::vec4 color;

public:
  base(std::string gn, float &gw, float &gh, glm::vec2 &gc);

  bool check_borders();

  void move(glm::vec2 &gpos);
  void move(float &x, float &y);

  void toggle_flags(GUI_FLAGS f);
  void open();
  void close();

  void set_color(glm::vec3 &color);
  void set_transparency(float &t);

  void enslave(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<base> &gslave);
  void free_slave(std::string name);
  void check_slaves();

  void add_text(std::string text, glm::vec2 position, glm::vec3 color,
                GLfloat scale=1.0f, GLfloat padx=8.0f, GLfloat pady=8.0f);

  virtual void handle_mouse();
  virtual void handle_keys();

};

#endif // _GUI_BASE_HPP_
```

If more details are needed, I can copy them here, I just didn't want to spam too much code.

The compiler simply gives two errors:

> obj\Debug\Sources\gui_base.o:c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\gthr-default.h|402|first defined here|
>
> ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

All variables and funtions are defined in gui_base.cpp (including the virtual ones).
I am more or less transferring it "into" the namespace, as I had it working as a "normal" class in the global namespace just fine, so I assume it has soemthing to do with it. But given my lack of experience, I am a little overwhelmed by the small amount of (for me) understandable information given by the compiler error.

Most entries I could find were multiple definition errors regarding definitions in the header files, which - in my understanding - I do not have in my header.

Here is the gui_base.cpp:

```
#include "../Headers/gui_base.hpp"

namespace input_handler
{
  std::unique_ptr<s_mouse> up_mouse;
  std::map<uint32_t, bool> KEYS;
}

GUI::base::base(std::string gn, float &gw, float &gh, glm::vec2 &gc) : m_name(gn),
                                                                          m_width(gw),
                                                                          m_height(gh),
                                                                          m_center(gc)
{
  resource_manager::calc_tlbr(m_tlbr, m_center, m_width, m_height);
}

void GUI::base::handle_keys()
{

}
void GUI::base::handle_mouse()
{

}
bool GUI::base::check_borders()
{
  if(input_handler::up_mouse->position.x > m_tlbr[0].x &&
     input_handler::up_mouse->position.y < m_tlbr[0].y &&
     input_handler::up_mouse->position.x < m_tlbr[1].x &&
     input_handler::up_mouse->position.y > m_tlbr[1].y)
      return true;
  else
    return false;
}

void GUI::base::move(glm::vec2 &gpos)
{
  m_center = gpos;
  resource_manager::calc_tlbr(m_tlbr, m_center, m_width, m_height);
}

void GUI::base::move(float &x, float &y)
{
  m_center = glm::vec2(x,y);
  resource_manager::calc_tlbr(m_tlbr, m_center, m_width, m_height);
}

void GUI::base::enslave(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<base> &gslave)
{
  m_slaves[name] = gslave;
}

void GUI::base::check_slaves()
{
  for(auto iter : m_slaves)
  {
    if(iter.second->check_borders())
    {
      if(iter.second->m_flags & GUI_OPEN)
        iter.second->check_slaves();
    }
    else
      continue;
  }
}

void GUI::base::open()
{
    toggle_flags(GUI_OPEN | GUI_DRAW | GUI_CLOSED);
    if(!m_slaves.empty())
    {
        for(auto iter : m_slaves)
        {
            iter.second->open();
        }
    }

}

void GUI::base::toggle_flags(GUI_FLAGS f)
{
  m_flags ^= f;
}

void GUI::base::close()
{
    toggle_flags(GUI_OPEN | GUI_DRAW | GUI_CLOSED);
    if(!m_slaves.empty())
    {
        for(auto iter : m_slaves)
        {
            iter.second->close();
        }
    }
}
void GUI::base::add_text(std::string text, glm::vec2 position, glm::vec3 color,
                GLfloat scale, GLfloat padx, GLfloat pady)
{
  m_textblock = GUI::textblock(position, color, scale, padx, pady, text);
}
```

EDIT:
My class is declared in the nsp_gui.hpp file, which is included in the gui_text.hpp file (which is included in the regarding gui_base file)

there I declare my class as follows:

```
#ifndef _NSP_GUI_HPP_
#define _NSP_GUI_HPP_

namespace GUI
{
  //the renderer class
  class renderer;
  class base;
  class window;
  //init function -> text will be in the GUI
  extern void init_gui();
}

#endif // _NSP_GUI_HPP_
```

Blame on me - I found this in the build log (wasn't aware that there one.. sorry):

> obj\Debug\Sources\gui_text.o:gui_text.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of GUI::textblock_storage[abi:cxx11]
>   obj\Debug\Sources\gui_base.o:gui_base.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
>   obj\Debug\Sources\gui_window.o:gui_window.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of GUI::textblock_storage[abi:cxx11]

textblock storage i declared in gui_text.hpp:
(gui_window "simply" inherits from gui_base, so this may be why it is occuring in there)

```
#ifndef _GUI_TEXT_HPP_
#define _GUI_TEXT_HPP_

#include "nsp_rmng.hpp"
#include "nsp_gui.hpp"
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

namespace GUI
{
  extern void init_alphabet();
  extern void write();
  class textblock
  {
  public:
    glm::vec2 position;
    glm::vec4 instancing;
    glm::vec3 color;
    GLfloat scale, padx, pady;
    std::string text;
    void calc_offsets();
    textblock(){};
    textblock(glm::vec2 &p, glm::vec3 &c,
                GLfloat &s, GLfloat &px, GLfloat &py,
                std::string &t);

  };
  std::map<std::string, textblock> textblock_storage;
}

#endif // _GUI_TEXT_HPP_
```

The strange thing is that I do not define it anywhere. I do not use it yet either in the base nor text.cpp, even though I want to use it within the gui_text.cpp. Shouldn't it be just an unknown reference then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> obj\Debug\Sources\gui_base.o:c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\gthr-default.h|402|first defined here|

It is not the error message.

Class `class base` in the namespace `GUI` should be declared like follow

```
namespace GUI {
class base {
  ...
};
} // namespace GUI
```

And definitions should be in the namespace too.

```
namespace GUI {
base::base(std::string gn, float &gw, float &gh, glm::vec2 &gc) {
  ...
}
} // namespace GUI
```

**UPDATE** after OP edited his answer.

> The strange thing is that I do not define it anywhere.

You defined the variable `textblock_storage` in the header, the header is included twice at least, thus the variable takes places in obj-files several times. Declare it in the header like bellow

```
extern std::map<std::string, textblock> textblock_storage;
```

And define it once in only one .cpp file

```
std::map<std::string, textblock> textblock_storage;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.
I indeed declare my class within the Namespace GUI in nsp_gui.hpp (which is by itself included in gui_text.hpp). I edited my question to reflect this. Is it still necessary to define the class within the namespace then?

Comment: Your forward declarations are ok. Yes, it is necessary to place declarations and definitions into the namespace. You must see it in first error messages that you do not want to post.

Comment: My problem is that these are the only line I get from my compiler.. there are no "error messages I do not want to post" - why should there be some? I want help and there is no use for me to hide error messages. 
Putting my class into the namespace brackets does unfortunatly not help, I get the same error/ compiler message posted in the question: `namespace GUI{class base{//see above};}`